# how to dynamically loop through values in Jmeter response

Tags: xml, soap, jmeter

I have a SOAP request which gives me multiple PID's in the response, I am able to successfully extract these PID's from the response and use them in the next request but in the next request it takes first value of the PID'd only and does not pass on the rest of the values in the response, in short does not loop. I have to send a new SOAP request each time with all the PID's I recieve in the response.

I have tried using for EACH controller and some other controller but does not seem to work.

Comment: I recieve 123456, 234567, 345678 I am using xpath extractor in the response and successfully getting all the values extracted but pass these values to the new request it just takes the first values instead taking all the values one by one in different requests

Comment: If I use the loop controller it just keeps on repeating the same PID in different requests... I need it to have diffent PID each time it creates a new request... so here how do I assign the new PID each time a new request is created

Comment: Finally I did discover the ForEach controller to get over this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did discover the ForEach controller to get over this problem

InputVar is the one that will get me xpath variable from previous request

Output Var is the one that I will use in the next request

basicall array of values